# Checking for an active process in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I've got a rather buggy version of php-fpm (ubuntu) running, I'm looking for a script (which will be run as cronjob).. that check if php5-fpm is running, and if its not.. to re-execute it.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if a process is running using the `pgrep` command.

```
victor:~$ pgrep bash
5554
victor:~$
```

As you can see, it returns the process ID of all matching processes.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the ps command to detect running processes and grep for the 'php-pfm' application - could be looking like that:

```
TEST=`ps -faxu |grep 'php-pfm'|grep -v 'grep'`
if [ -e  "$TEST" ]; then
    #not running... restart!
    php-fpm &
fi
```

You may try the man pages for 'ps' and 'grep'...

Edit: new code fragment including victors fix:

```
TEST=`ps -faxu |grep 'php-pfm'|grep -v 'grep'`
if [ -z  "$TEST" ]; then
    #not running... restart!
    php-fpm &
fi
```

--
Mayday

Comment: `-e` is used to check if a file exists, IIRC. I think you mean `-z`, right? `-z string` -- "True if the length of `string` is zero."

Comment: Additionally, there's a configuration option in FPM that allows you to set the pidfile for the FPM master (I think it's just called `pid_file`).  You could possibly replace that first line with...  `TEST=ps `cat /path/to/fpm.pid``  (that last backtick should be included, but I can't figure out the positioning to get the parser to work)

Comment: You can do `if ps ...` without the brackets or variable. You will need to do `grep -qs` or redirect the output to `/dev/null`. You can do `grep [p]hp-pfm` and eliminate the `grep -v`. Note that parsing the output of `ps` is ripe for false positives.

Comment: Mayday, from the 2nd example.. I get this error:  Warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See http://procps.sf.net/faq.html

Comment: @user349418: The ps command works fine on my computer. Maybe there are different versions of ps. A glance into the man page should help.